# How to make space triangle with Python

Tags: python, for-loop

I want to make a space triangle with Python.  I made a triangle like this:

```
    ` 
   ` ` 
  `   ` 
 `     ` 
` ` ` ` `
```

using this code:

```
line = 5
print((line-1) * " " + "` ")
for i in range(1,line-1):
    print((line-i-1)* " " +  "`" + (2*i -1)*" " + "` ")
print((line) * "` ")
```

now I want to reverse that triangle, so it should be like this:

```
 ` ` ` ` ` `  
  `       `
   `     `
    `   `
     ` `
      `
```

but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: reverse the range

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just reverse the `range` and the prints:

```
line = 5
print((line) * "` ")
for i in range(line-1, 1, -1):
    print((line-i-1)* " " +  "`" + (2*i -1)*" " + "` ")
print((line-1) * " " + "` ")
```

Here you have the [live example](https://repl.it/repls/BluevioletWheatMicrobsd)